# .Net debugging: how to suspend only one thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio, debugging

I need to debug a production server while users continue to use it. When a breakpoint hits, I want other threads that serve other users' requests to continue working while I inspect the variables in my thread and decide to step over or step into methods.

In Java, you have a choice between "Suspend thread" and "Suspend VM" when a breakpoint is hit. But I cannot find the equivalent functionality in .Net.

Comment: .NET code is strictly converted to machine code, there is no interpreter or VM that could be "suspended".  Freezing a thread is well supported, it must be done while the program is in a break state.  It will not resume running when you continue testing until you thaw it again.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried this: when my breakpoint was hit, I froze the current thread and resumed the application. Technically it should be just what I wanted: my thread is stopped and all other threads are working in full speed. Except that the debug windows no longer work. The framework (or IDE) is not smart enough to wake up the frozen thread to evaluate watch expression.

Comment: I can't see how using an interpretter could have helped. This is not a limitation if the native OS threading model, as the JVM seems to be able to handle my scenario. And the JVM JIT compiler also compiles the bytecode to native code just the way .Net's jitter does.

Comment: It is simply not the way it works in .NET.  Watch expressions are only evaluated in break state.  You need to stop assuming that .NET needs to work like Java because that's what you are used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While debugging open the thread window: `Debug->Windows->Threads`. Right-click on the thread(s) you want to suspend and select `freeze`. Use `thaw` to enable thread execution again.

Comment: But all the threads are already stopped when the breakpoint hits. I want to have them run, not stop them. I think what you are suggesting is actually the opposite of what I need.

Comment: After the breakpoint hits, freeze threads you do not want to run. Then continue execution and all threads except the one you froze wil run. The netto effect is what you asked for, no?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. So far so good. But the problem is that when I continue execution I cannot debug anymore. The watch window is no longer available. Even the threads window is disabled, so even to resume execution of my paused thread I have to stop the world again.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works, and there's no way around it. (as Hans already pointed out in the comments on the question as I just noticed). If you want to watch variables while the program is running, use tracepoints (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/232dxah7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, essentially a breakpoint which briefly stops execution and logs variables and then continues) or plain logging.

Answer (score 1):

For whom it may interest, I wrote a small helper that does its best to provide this functionality in Visual Studio (in async context).

https://gist.github.com/olivier-spinelli/c075b672c26a3ba26801e55be3d3e5d9

I had no better idea than that... Any ideas or evolutions are welcome!